# ng-flow setting CSRF token on header

Tags: angularjs, ng-flow

i could not find a way setting the X-XSRF-TOKEN header when using file uploads with flow.js.

Since flow.js seems to not use the $http resource to post files i need to set the header explicitly.

Here is what is did:

**profile.edit.html:**

```
<div class="row" flow-init="{target: 'rest/account/uploadImage'}" 
                        flow-file-added="processFiles($file, $event, $flow)"
                        flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()" >
...
<img type="file" flow-btn ng-if="$flow.files.length" flow-img="$flow.files[$flow.files.length-1]" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive" />

</div>
```

**controller.js:**

```
function profileCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $window, $cookies, toaster, 

    $scope.processFiles = function(file, event, flow) {
        flow.defaults.headers = function(file, chunk, isTest) {
            return {
                'X-CSRFToken': $cookies.get("csrftoken")
    };}
```

But unfortunally nothing is set. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow.js does not use $http service, because of this you have to set csrf token manually to each request.

It should be:

```
<div flow-init="{headers: {'XCSRF-TOKEN': csrf}}">
</div>
```

**Or:**

html file:

```
<div flow-init="setToken();">
    ...
</div>
```

js file:

```
 function profileCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $window, $cookies, toaster){

    $scope.setToken = function() {
       $scope.options = {
         headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': $cookies.get("csrftoken");
         }
       };
    }
```

}

**OR:**

Html File :

```
  <div  flow-init flow-files-submitted="uploadFiles($files, $event, $flow);"
                flow-file-added="!!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[$file.getExtension()]"

                flow-name="flow" flow-upload-started="uploadStart($flow);"
                flow-file-success="fileUploadSucces($file, $message)"
                flow-complete="fileUploadsComplete();">

....
  </div>
```

JS file :

```
 function profileCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $window, $cookies, toaster){

    $scope.uploadStart = function($flow){   
        $flow.opts.target = "rest/account/uploadImage";
        $flow.opts.headers =  {'X-CSRFToken' : $cookies.get("csrftoken")};
    }

    $scope.fileUploadSucces = function($file, $message){
        //Upload Success

    };

    $scope.fileUploadsComplete = function(){
       //Complated Upload

    };

    $scope.uploadFiles = function($file, $message, $flow){
        //Uploading
        $rootScope.$flow = $flow;
        $rootScope.$flow.upload();
   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks jackk. Can you also tell me how you read out the csrf token from this code snipplet you send me? when i use 'csrf' as a literal it does not work right?

Comment: first of all thanks for this great answer. i tried the last example you send me. it turns out that my issue is not setting the header but calling the 'get' function on $cookies object return an error saying: $cookies.get is not a function. Although in debugger the $cookies object seems to be ok.  In other words: i can set the header correctly now but can not ready out the cookie inorder to retrieve the proper data for the header. Arrrgh!

Comment: Ok solved it. Seems the syntax is different in my angular version. Using $flow.opts.headers =  {'X-XSRF-TOKEN' : $cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"]}; solved my issue. See also https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: I thought it was worth cookies.get ("csrftoken") it. s.a :)

Comment: Yes me too. API states that getters and setters were introduced with angular 1.4. i am using 1.3. "Up until Angular 1.3, $cookies exposed properties that represented the current browser cookie values. In version 1.4, this behavior has changed, and $cookies now provides a standard api of getters, setters etc."